# Switch statement isn't letting me add the last element of the ArrayLists into a new ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

For each case in the `switch` statement, the function displays a sub-menu which allows the user to choose what item they would like and returns an `ArrayList` and adds it to the `allItem` `ArrayList`. Everything runs exactly how it is supposed to be until I added the lines to add the elements into the `ArrayList` `totalCost`. Instead of it looping back to the first print statement it gets stuck doing the function the user just entered and does it multiple times before getting back into the original menu and doesn't add the `ArrayList` of the items correctly anymore. After taking out the lines where I indicated with problems everything works fine, but I just need to get the last index of the `ArrayList` of each function I called at each `switch` statements and add it into `totalCost` `ArrayList`.

```
 public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> itemMenu(){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> totalCost = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean chosen = false;

        do {
            System.out.println("\nWelcome to the store, what would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("1.) Get Boba\n2.) Get Coffee\n3.) Get a Pastry\n4.) Get a Macaron\n" +
                    "5.) Get a Cookie\n6.) Done");
            int userChoice = 0;
            userChoice = in.nextInt();

            switch (userChoice) {
                case 1:
                    allItems.add(bobaDrink()); // Adds the returned ArrayList into an ArrayList of all items
                    totalCost.add(bobaDrink().get(bobaDrink().size() - 1)); //Problem
                    break;
                case 2:
                    allItems.add(coffeeDrink());
                    totalCost.add(coffeeDrink().get(coffeeDrink().size() - 1)); //Problem
                    break;

                case 3:
                    allItems.add(pastryItem());
                    totalCost.add(pastryItem().get(pastryItem().size() - 1)); //Problem
                    break;

                case 4:
                    allItems.add(macaronItem());
                    totalCost.add(macaronItem().get(macaronItem().size() - 1)); //Problem
                    break;
                case 5:
                    allItems.add(cookieItem());
                    totalCost.add(cookieItem().get(cookieItem().size() - 1)); //Problem
                    break;

                case 6:
                    chosen = true;
                    break;

                default : System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }


        }
        while(!chosen);

        System.out.println(allItems);
        System.out.println(totalCost);

        return allItems;

    }
```

If anyone needs any more clarification on any more things on this let me know!

Comment: could you please share what one of your functions i.e. bobaDrink does? if it just returns the not empty ArrayList<String> it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this code is strange

```
allItems.add(bobaDrink()); // Adds the returned ArrayList into an ArrayList of all items
totalCost.add(bobaDrink().get(bobaDrink().size() - 1));
```

as you are calling `bobaDrink()` three times

I suggest

```
ArrayList<String> tmp = bobaDrink();
allItems.add (tmp);
totalCost.add(tmp.get(tmp.size() - 1));
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? What *is* the question?

Comment: @shmosel The OP has sent up some method that prompt the user for more input *(gets stuck doing the function the user just entered and does it multiple times)* and he wonders why the user keeps on getting prompted for the same information when calling the same method mutiple times - Thats my reading of it

Comment: @shmosel If I am wrong, then please let me know and I will delete

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Oh it worked! Thank you so much I was having a lot of trouble trying to figure it out!